# Visual Studio wont download

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I wanted to install C++ from Visual Studio 2017, but it wouldn't.
So, I uninstalled Visual Studio 2017, then tried to install it again, but always goes to this

[image]

So then I clicked on "view log" and this is what I saw this
[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is more about coding related questions. I'm not sure this is the best place for your problem.

Comment: Just google the error message, you'll [find this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/60433/installer-sorry-the-product-definitions-failed-to.html).

Answer (score 0):

OH!  I just deleted anyTHING that even knows Visual Studio.  Now I can run the installer again!